# vim edit - Editing in different position of each line at the same time

Tags: vim

I wonder if there is a rapid method to change this:

```
foo: ''
foobarfoo: ''
foof: ''
fooba: ''
foobarbar: ''
foooobar: ''
```

to

```
foo: 'foo'
foobarfoo: 'foobarfoo'
foof: 'foof'
fooba: 'fooba'
foobarbar: 'foobarbar'
foooobar: 'foooobar'
```

Obviously, I want to paste the word in line into the parentheses.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this line works for your example:

```
%s/\v([^:]*)(:\s*).*/\1\2'\1'/
```

or you love playing it with macro:

```
qq0ywf'pjq
```

then `99@q` (99 is how many times do you want to play the macro)

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry which part do you have problem? I think the regex is pretty straightforward.

Comment: yep. regexp is simple. `.*/\1\2'\1'/` - this interesting.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry \1 represent the content between () and \2 represent the second

Comment: i think macro way is more simpler then regexp way)

Answer (score 4):

Kent's regex answer is good, but I often do these kinds of things with the `g` Ex command, simply because I think so firmly in terms of normal mode operations, and they often end up very short:

```
:g/^/norm yw$P
```